# Infimum of $\int_{-1}^{2} x^2|x-t|\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find infimum of the function $$[1,2]\ni t \mapsto \int_{-1}^{2} x^2|x-t|\ dx.$$

Is my solution correct?

$$\begin{align} F(t)=&\int_{-1}^{2} x^2|x-t|\ dx=
\int_{-1}^{t} x^2(-x+t) \ dx+\int_{t}^{2} x^2(x-t) \ dx=\\ 
=&\int_{-1}^{t} -x^3+tx^2) \ dx+\int_{t}^{2} x^3-tx^2 \ dx=\\ 
=&\left(\frac{-x^4}{4}+\frac{tx^3}{3}\right)\Bigg |_{-1}^{t}+\left(\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{-tx^3}{3}\right)\Bigg |_{t}^{2}=\\
=&\frac{-t^4}{2}+\frac{2t^4}{3}-\frac{7t}{3}+\frac{17}{3}=\\
=&\frac{2t^4-28t+51}{12} \end{align}$$
And now I just have to find infimum of result function on given interval.

Comment: Looks good so far to me.

Comment: Yes, and since the function is continous on a compact interval there is a minimum. Hence, infimum= minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is entirely correct. I would still double check the last couple of lines, but the general idea is good.

Comment: Anyways, I was more unsure about making this integral a normal one, without absolute value. But if I'm right, that's good.

Comment: @Jules Actually, I made a typo myself, your answer is entirely correct.

Comment: I think you should have +1/4 and +t/3 in the first row.